# How to hide a Submit button on Oracle Workflow Notification after clicking it?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In an Oracle workflow process, I have a notification with a custom response of type "Submit". I want to hide this button after the user clicks it so he can't send the notification more than one time.

All I can find is `#HIDE_REASSIGN` Attribute to hide the Reassign button and `#HIDE_MOREINFO` Attribute to hide the Request Information button. But I want to hide a custom button based on a condition (clicking one time)